# How to specify github link as requirements for buildozer

Tags: python, buildozer

I know that I can specify the version of a module in buildozer.spec as

```
requirements = python3==3.7.x  #Just an example
```

But I am using a module whose new release hasn't been released yet, I installed it from Github. How do I specify that here?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the link of the zip file.

for example

```
requirements = python3, https://github.com/kivy/plyer/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
```

Buildozer will take care rest of it.